# Sorting on non-linear topology

Tags: graphs, sorting, search-algorithms

**Disclaimer.** What I'm going to ask about below may seem to be "Topological sorting". To my understanding, it is not. The latter runs in linear time, while I'm looking for a modification of the regular sort, which is at $N\log N$.

**Remark.** I'm doing the sort in the reverse order, to use the analogy with heights and masses.

Let us reformulate the sorting problem in the following way. Let us introduce two sets:

1. A set of sites (positions) $s_a,\,a=1..N$. Those are assigned certain 'heights' $h[s_a]$, which in the case of usual sorting can be simply $h[s_a]=a$.
2. A set of objects (numbers) $x_i,\,i=1..N$ which are assigned numerical values $m[x_i]$ (according to which the sorting will be performed). In the case of usual sorting, $m[x_i]$ are the numbers to be sorted.

The problem of sorting can be viewed as assigning to each object $x_i$ a site $s_a$ in such a way that for all assignments $\{x_i\to s_a; x_j\to s_b\}$:
$$
h[s_a] > h[s_b] \Longrightarrow m[x_i]\leq m[x_j]
$$

The physical visualization of this problem is a vertical stack of massive balls. Sorting them is equivalent to arranging them in such a way that heavier ones have lower height.

I first wanted to generalize the problem to "higher dimensions", i.e. to assume that the balls can stay in a $2$-dimensional grid, in a bucket, etc. However, I realized that from the computational point of view these settings are equivalent. In other words, whether we have a $2d$ grid with $nm$ balls in each row or a box with $n\times m$ balls in each layer makes no difference.

So, I decided to generalize the problem to an arbitrary topology (which can be reduced to the $2$-dimensional problem actually).

1. A set of sites (positions) $s_a,\,a=1..N$. Those are assigned certain 'heights' $h[s_a]$. Repetitions are allowed: $h[s_a]=h[s_b]$ for $a\neq b$ is OK.
2. A set of objects (numbers) $x_i,\,i=1..N$ which are assigned numerical values $m[x_i]$.

Again, we want to assign to each object a site in accordance with the same requirement as above.

Clearly, the brute-force solution for the most general set of 'heights' and 'masses' runs in $N \log N$. One simply sorts the objects according to their 'mass', and then fills the sites, starting from the 'highest' or the 'lowest' one.

**Question.** Has there been done any research for some particular cases? Clearly, if all the 'heights' are equal, the problem is trivial (which, I guess, means that it is solved in linear time). The first thing coming to my mind would be considering the case of "levels of same lengths",
$$
h[s_a]=\lceil a/r\rceil,\,r\in\mathbb{N}
$$
I would actually expect that this can be done faster than $N\log N$ (I'd assume that $r$ should enter the answer).

Comment: Do you have any particular case in mind you want to ask about? If not, I don't think the question is ripe for an answer yet (you're basically asking us to invent some case that might be interesting, and then find an algorithm for it; but as we have no idea what you might find interesting vs not, that seems too vague/ill-specified to be usefully answerable).

Comment: I think the notation might be a tiny bit clearer if you numbered the sites and object $1..N$, so you write $h[a]$ and $m[i]$ and talk about site $a$ and object $i$ instead of $h[s_a]$ and $m[x_i]$ and site $s_a$ and object $x_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are $k$ distinct heights, you can sort in $O(n \log k)$ time using a heap or balanced binary tree.  Even better, you can sort with expected time $O(n + k \log k)$, if you use a hashtable.

This leads to a solution to your problem with the corresponding complexity.